# xscreensaver lock screen with Unity lock screen in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome, lock-screen, xscreensaver

I have searched many posts about "xscreensaver lock screen to use unity lock screen" such as:
[How do I configure xscreensaver to use the GNOME lockscreen on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491516/how-do-i-configure-xscreensaver-to-use-the-gnome-lockscreen-on-ubuntu-14-04)
But I still don't know how to make it works.

I have *removed the `gnome-screensaver`* and there is no `/usr/share/applications/gnome-screensaver.desktop`. But there is one `~/.config/autostart/gnome-screensaver.desktop`.

And I have add the `xscreensaver` entry into the "Startup Applications Preferences".
Here is the `xscreensaver` setting:
[image]

And I have set the "Brightness & Lock" in setting panel:[image]

And the final result is that the screensaver works, but **it can't lock screen with the "unity lock screen"**.
And my system is Ubuntu 16.04 and the desktop environment is `Unity` (The output of `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` is `Unity`). (Though I don't know what is the difference between gnome and unity, I haven't change the desktop enviroment.) So how can I make the lock screen work with the Unity lock screen?

Thanks.