# How to use xscreensaver on Kubuntu 18.04; 20.04 (KDE, Plasma)

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, kde, plasma, xscreensaver

How can the KDE standard lock screen be replaced by the xscreensaver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- install xscreensaver packages
- disable kde screen lock
  [image: disable kde screen lock]
- let kde autostart xscreensaver on login: make a new entry with `xscreensaver -no-splash`
  [image: kde autostart]
- create a lockscreen keyboard shortcut in the kde settings (possibly using the kde lock shortcut for the xscreensaver, thereby overriding it): `xscreensaver-command -lock`
  [image: create new locking keyboard shortcut]
- assign a suitable shortcut
  [image: keyboar shortcut (assign)]
- adjust settings for the screensaver: `xscreensaver-command -prefs`
- after the next login, the xscreensaver should be available
- weblink: https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/man1.html#9
- examples

Squiral
[image: xscreensaver_Squiral]

XAnalogTV
[image: xscreensaver_XAnalogTV]

Pacman
[image: xscreensaver_Pacman]

IMSMap
[image: xscreensaver_IMSMap]

Kumppa
[image: xscreensaver_Kumppa]

BSOD
[image: xscreensaver_BSOD]

Pong
[image: xscreensaver_Pong]

Fireworks
[image: xscreensaver_Coral]

Coral
[image: xscreensaver_Fireworks]

Polyhedra
[image: xscreensaver_Polyhedra]

Comment: fantastic, thank you. the old screen hacks are still the best, plus it's possible to set up "modern" ones like on a Macbook:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/21608/use-video-file-as-a-screensaver

Comment: it would be nice to have xanalogtv and others play (locally stored) movies (instead of showing only one image for some time)

Comment: I face the issue with this on KDE, which is - after resuming computer from sleep, xscreensaver gets activated. Did anyone else faced it?