# How can i use a video as a screensaver on Lubuntu 19.04?

Tags: lubuntu, screensaver

I want to use a .mp4 video as a screensaver, any suggestion?

Comment: Do you mean LXQt 0.14.1 ?? as Lubuntu releases are *yy.mm* in format, and that number doesn't make sense as *year.month*.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please edit your question and provide additional details. Which version of Ubuntu/Lubuntu are you using?

Comment: sorry, it's lubuntu 19.04 and 0.14.1 is LXQt, I was mislead by a friend of mine

Comment: @Pirkk A web search revealed: LXQt uses xdg-screensaver from xdg-utils for screen locking which only works with XScreenSaver and xautolock in LXQt session. You can use it or another screen locker by itself.  See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LXQt for details. That suggests https://askubuntu.com/a/808569/197910 or https://askubuntu.com/a/817603/197910  will work.